# Cant import module in site packages directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have been trying to import a module named requests, it is located in site-packages folder. It was installed via pip but every time i try to import it i get the error "*ImportError: No module named 'request'*"

I am using "import requests" to import.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(max_pages):
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
    url = "http://www.ebay.ie/sch/Laptops-Netbooks/175672/i.html?_catref=1&_pgn=" + str(page) + "&_skc=50&rt=nc"
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'img'}):
        href = "http://www.ebay.ie" + link.get('href')
        title = link.string
        print(href)
        print(title)
    page += 1

 spider(1)
```

I'm wondering if its to do with my enviroment variables or if i have installed them wrong.

Comment: You should use `import requests`. I guess this was a typo.

Comment: still not importing it.

Comment: I would check @Orions answer.

Comment: python3 isnt a recognized command i use python not python3, this assumes im using linux?

Comment: windows unfortunately. and no need to reply il close the question now actually. i dual booted ubuntu instead, and now using ubuntu for python stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have installed [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/) module for `Python 2` but you are working on `Python 3`. Use the below command to install it for Python 3:

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

Source: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

`import request` should be `import requests`

Comment: just fixed it.! but it still doesn't import.